# asp.net images in image buttons to remain stationary

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have 3 image buttons on the left, top and right of the main body content.

I want these fixed in position so that when I scroll up or down, these remain in position.

This page has a master page. I'm using ContentPlaceHolders:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="left_col_fbodyContentPlaceHolder"
    runat="Server">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="LeftImageButton" runat="server" Width="233px" Height="100%" ImageUrl="~/images/100_3445sr194k.jpg" PostBackUrl="~/test1.aspx" />       
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="upper_body_ContentPlaceHolder" runat="Server">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="TopImageButton" runat="server" Width="770px" Height="40px" ImageUrl="~/images/100_3496sr194k.jpg" PostBackUrl="~/test1.aspx" />        
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="right_col_fbodyContentPlaceHolder"
    runat="Server">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="RightImageButton" runat="server" Width="233px" Height="100%" ImageUrl="~/images/100_3496sr194k.jpg" PostBackUrl="~/test1.aspx" />        
</asp:Content>
```

If it's possible, I'm hoping someone can show me how.

Comment: Show what you've tried and how it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AjaxControlToolkits`'s `AlwaysVisibleControl` solves your problem. For more details see [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/krishnasarala/always-visible-control-extender-in-Asp-Net-ajax/)

Comment: Thanks. This proved more useful than I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1.: use Fixed position in css

```
<div class='fixedDiv'>
<asp:ImageButton ID="LeftImageButton" runat="server" Width="233px"    Height="100%" ImageUrl="~/images/100_3445sr194k.jpg" PostBackUrl="~/test1.aspx" />
</div>
```

In css:

```
.fixedDiv{
position:fixed;
}
```

Another option is set fixed height to body, and overflow:auto to the div which contains the content. the scroll appears on the content div while the screen stay fixed.

```
<asp:Content ID="Bodycontent" ContentPlaceHolderID="BodyContent"
runat="Server">
<div style='height:900px;overflow:auto'>

</div>  
</asp:Content>
```